# How to use setValue:forKey: function with NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm try to use the functions `-setValue:forKey:` and get the value using `-valueForKey:`

Example:

```
NSArray *rootarr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name", @"address", @"title", nil];
[rootarr setValue:array forKey:@"n"];
NSArray *getArr = [rootarr valueForKey:@"n"];
```

But the getArr array I got is not equal the array I set (array).

Could you please tell me what's wrong I met. And what's the way to use these functions?

Answer (score 5):

`NSArray`'s `setValue:forKey:` method is used for [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), not for using an array as an associative container. You need to use `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"name", @"address", @"title", nil];
[rootDict setValue:array forKey:@"n"];
NSArray *getArr = [rootDict valueForKey:@"n"];
```

Comment: While one hase to use NSMutableDictionary for key-value coding, NSArray does have a `setValue:forKey:` method. It does something different however!

Comment: @thundersteele You're right, I completely forgot about the key value coding! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An array isn't a key-value store, which you appear to want to use it as. I think you want an NSDictionary instead (or more precisely NSMutableDictionary if you want to modify it after its created).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1408301-setvalue?language=objc) `setValue:forKey:`

Invokes setValue:forKey: on each of the array's items using the specified value and key.

Practical uses are when you want to set the same value to each element of the array

```
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
NSArray *arr = @[label1, label2];
[arr setValue:@"bye" forKey:@"text"];
NSLog(@"%@ %@",label1.text, label2.text);   // bye bye
```

in your example "getArr" is an empty array because your "rootarr" doesn't have elements, otherwise you receive a `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` into the contained objects that are not compliant for the assigned key

Answer (score -1):

You can't add objects to an `NSArray` after it is created. You have to use `NSMutableArray` in order to do that.

Comment: This should be a commentary not an answer.