# NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have multiple `NSDictionaries` inside an `NSMutableArray`. A short hand example is below. `comparisonChart` is the `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{
                       @"Tube": @"10/0",
                       @"Dress":@"3"
                       };

[self.comparisonChart setValue:dict1 forKey@"0"];
// key 0 as i wish to use numeric indexes, comparisonChart is mutable array
```

When i wish to extract the value for a key i've tried:

```
[self.comparisonChart valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", value]]
//where value is numeric value e.g 0
```

However this returns null. ive also tried `objectForKey:value` with the same result.

How do i go about this?

**update:**

```
[self.comparisonChart insertObject:dict23 atIndex:1];

NSLog(@"chart: %@", [self.comparisonChart objectAtIndex:1]);

Output: chart: (null)   // why is this?
```

Comment: Is comparisonChart also a NSDictionary?

Comment: no comparison chart is the NSMutableArray

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use setValue:forKey: function with NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628864/how-to-use-setvalueforkey-function-with-nsarray)

Comment: Why don't you simply access the array at index `value`?

Comment: For an array, you should use `insertObject:atIndex:` to add an object to a specific point. `setValue:forKey:` will not work.

Comment: Umm, you can't insert an object at an index that doesn't exist already. Now you're getting into a world of "what is your code doing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use objectForKey for one, you should also be using subscripts instead;

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"Tube": @"10/0",
                       @"Dress":@"3"};

NSMutableDictionary *comparisonChart = [NSMutableDictionary new];
comparisonChart[@"0"] = dict1;

NSLog(@"My value: %@", comparisonChart[@"0"]);
```

Here's the code copy and pasted from AppDelegate and working:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = @{@"Tube": @"10/0",
                            @"Dress":@"3"};

    NSMutableDictionary *comparisonChart = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    comparisonChart[@"0"] = dict1;

    NSLog(@"My value: %@", comparisonChart[@"0"]);

    return YES;
}
```

Edit:

To append on the question above please ensure the index being inserted is valid per the documentation below:

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject:atIndex:)

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject
             atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

> ```
> Parameters
> anObject  
> The object to add to the array's content. This value must not be nil.
> IMPORTANT
> Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if anObject is nil.
> index 
> The index in the array at which to insert anObject. This value must not be greater than the count of elements in the array.
> IMPORTANT
> Raises an NSRangeException if index is greater than the number of elements in the array.
> Discussion
> If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room.
>
> Note that NSArray objects are not like C arrays. That is, even though you specify a size when you create an array, the specified size
> ```
>
> is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0. This
>   means that you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the
>   current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two
>   objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2.
>   Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds; if you try to add an object at
>   index 3 (when the size of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an
>   exception.
>
> ```
> Import Statement
> import Foundation
>
> Availability
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```

Comment: `comparisonChart[@"0"] = dict1` throws an error, and the overall answer is a short-version of the other answer by JustAnotherCoder.

Comment: I answered at the same time >.<. Any who, if you get an error at comparisonChart[@"0"] = dict1 that means that comparisonChart is not a mutable dictionary. You may want to throw a breakpoint at that point in code and type po comparisonChart in the console to check what type of object you have at that point in time. You also may want to try cleaning your workspace if all else fails.

Comment: Also, read the exception being thrown. It most likely states why the above isn't working (when the above is valid).

Comment: i understand your answer, and belive it to be correct but i cannot get it working here. all i get is null. i'm doing the exact same as your answer, the only difference is that it is done over 2 methods, viewDidLoad & a custom one. the dictionaries are local to viewDidload. could this be why?

Comment: No, the retain count of the dictionaries should be +1 when added to the array. There's something funky going on where either scope/access/or what not is not what you'd expect. This is why you should start breakpointing your code and checking your objects. Ensure your objects are initialized correctly and your accessing the correct ones at the correct times.

Answer (score 1):

If `self.comparisonChart` is a NSMutableArray then you add the NSDictionary like so:

```
[self.comparisonChart addObject: dict1];
```

or you may specify the index like so:

```
[self.comparisonChart insertObject: dict1 atIndex:desiredIndex];
```

To retrieve the NSDictionary object you must call:

```
[self.comparisonChart objectAtIndex:indexNumber];
```

Comment: I tried this method and it did not work. do i have to make the dictionaries global since the array is storing the pointer of the dictionary?